# Angular (click) method returns undefined

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

So I have a component, which shows a list of users and when I click on it it should open up the user detail view. However according to current code when I look into the network tab I see that a XHR request is made with undefined or Lastname, Firstname for some reason.

My Users.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AviorBackendService } from '../services/avior-backend.service';
import { UserCollection } from '../models/user-collection.model';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedItem: string;

  users: UserCollection;
  user: User;
  firstname: string;
  selectedUser: User;

  constructor(private aviorBackend: AviorBackendService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.aviorBackend.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.users = data['firstname'];
      console.log(this.users);
      console.log("getUserCollection() Data: ", data);
    });
  }

  clickItem(firstname) {
      this.aviorBackend.getUser(firstname).subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.selectedUser = data['user'];
      console.log(this.selectedUser);
      console.log("getUser() Data: ", data);
    });
  }
}
```

My Users.component.html:

```
<div class="list-area">

  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <p class="list-header">Element overview</p>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="filter" class="lb-sm">Filter</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="filter" id="filter">
    </div>

   <select size="20" multiple class="form-control" id="elementlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (click)="clickItem(firstname)">
      <!-- maybe add | async pipe -->
    <option *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user?.lastName}}, {{user?.firstName}}
      </option>
    </select>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="content-area">

  <div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="selectedUser?.id">

  <p>Element contents {{selectedUser?.id}}</p>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName" class="lb-sm">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstName" id="firstName" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.firstName">
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

My getUser() method:

```
// Get user
  getUser(firstname: string): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}user/firstname/${firstname}`;
    return this.client.get(API_URL, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => {
        return res || {};
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError())
    );
  }
```

My user.model.ts:

```
import { Role } from './role';

// was class and not interface!
export interface User {
    _id: number;
    mandator?: number;
    loginId: string;
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    password: string;
    eMail: string;
    group?: string;
    role?: Role;
    active?: boolean;
    token?: string;
}
```

My user-collection.model.ts:

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export interface UserCollection {

    user: User[];

}
```

My API response:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ogc.jpg

Comment: Well, you have a `clickItem(firstname)`. Did you intend to call like `clickItem(selectedItem.firstname)`?

Comment: @DanielB if I change it to `clickItem(selectedItem.firstname)` I get the following error: `Identifier 'firstname' is not defined. '<anonymous>' does not contain such a member` and it also doesn't work

Comment: You are not getting the selected name in `clickItem()` function which causes your API to fail, right??

Comment: And may I ask why you are using multiple attribute when you need one value?

Comment: @Arcteezy the XHR request to API contains the "Lastname, Firstname" format for some reason. What do you mean by multiple attribute? In which part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the problem properly, this change will make it work as per your requirement.

```
<select size="20" class="form-control" id="elementlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (change)="clickItem($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" value="{{user.firstname}}">
        {{user?.lastname}}, {{user?.firstname}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjma43

Comment: Good answer! There shouldn't be any `click` handlers but instead just the `change` handler!

Comment: `Identifier 'firstName' is not defined. 'User' does not contain such a member`. If I change it to firstname it still returns undefined :/

Comment: If I change it my list breaks and doesn't get populated even thought I change the variable names. Also, the backend returns **firstname** and not firstName.

Comment: The `console.log("Print first name: ", this.firstname);` returns undefined

Comment: Not **this.firstname**. Just **firstname** which is your function param.

Comment: Are you getting the name passed in function properly in your log??

Comment: It seems my API is broken, because I tried manually entering the URL and it would return null. Can you help me solve this too?

Comment: @Arcteezy the `console.log("Firstname param: ", req.params.firstname);` prints out the correct first name, yes

Comment: That is an entirely different issue. The problem you had in your client side is properly solved in the demo I provided. The backend issue can only be solved by seeing the code properly. You might wanna open a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you code is wrong. Try this in you html:

```
 <option *ngFor="let user of users"  (click)="clickItem($event, user.firstName)" >
            {{user?.lastName}}, {{user?.firstName}}
          </option>
```

and in your .ts you do:

```
clickItem(event, firstname)
{
  console.log("Print first name: ",firstname);
}
```

Comment: `ERROR ReferenceError: "firstname is not defined"`

Comment: @i edit my question. try with user.firstname in your html

Comment: From where is he gonna get the firstname??

Comment: @Arcteezy yeh you rigth, Firstname is undefined because he uses it after.

Comment: @Doflamingo19 it still returns undefined :/